# TinyXML Iterating over a Subtree

Tags: tinyxml, subtree, tinyxml++

Does anyone have code to iterate through the nodes of a subtree in TinyXML? IE: Given a parent, iterate through all its children and all of its children's children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Begemoth's answer sounds pretty good to me.

Here is a simplified version of TiXmlElement's Accept() method, that doesn't use a visitor and instead takes a TiXmlNode* as the parameter:

```
void TiXmlIterator::iterate(const TiXmlNode* el)
{
  cout << "Iterating Node " << el->Value() << endl;
  // More useful code here...

  for (const TiXmlNode* node=el->FirstChild(); node; node=node->NextSibling())
  {
    iterate(node);
  }
 // And/Or here.
}
```

The Accept() method takes a TiXmlVisitor as a parameter and does all the iterating for you, though. And you don't have to call it on the whole document, just the root node of the subtree you want to traverse. This way, you can define specific behavior for the subclasses of TiXmlNode, by overriding the right methods. Look at the implementation of TiXmlPrinter in [TinyXml's source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/) for a good example of how it's done.

In case you don't want to do that, here is another example:

```
bool MyTiXmlVisitor::Visit(const TiXmlText& text)
{
  cout << "Visiting Text: " << text.Value() << endl;

  return true; // This will ensure it keeps iterating
}
```

This will act on all text elements in the subtree of the node you call Accept() on. To act on *all* the elements, override the remaining virtual methods of TiXmlVisitor. Then, in the code where you want to iterate over the subtree, do the following:

```
subtree_root_node->Accept( my_tixmlvisitor_object );
```

Comment: The TiXmlPrinter code should be a good place to start. Is there anything you wanted to do at each node specifically?

Comment: Ok, edited my answer to specify what I and (I assume) Begemoth meant. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Visitor pattern implementation in the library. Create a class inherited from TiXmlVistor, override necessary methods like VisitElement, then call Accept() method for a particular node.

Comment: Not quite what i was asking for