# Remove all xml tags from a std::string

Tags: c++, xml, string, tinyxml

I have a `std::string xmlString = "<out><return>Hello</return></out>"` and I want to
remove all of the tags! (without an additional library, except tinyXML -> already loaded)

result -> Hello

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
std::string ClassA::ParseXMLOutput(std::string &xmlBuffer)
{
    bool copy = true;
    std::string plainString = "";   
    std::stringstream convertStream;

    // remove all xml tags
    for (int i=0; i < xmlBuffer.length(); i++)
    {                   
        convertStream << xmlBuffer[i];

        if(convertStream.str().compare("<") == 0) copy = false;
        else if(convertStream.str().compare(">") == 0) 
        {
            copy = true;
            convertStream.str(std::string());
            continue;
        }

        if(copy) plainString.append(convertStream.str());       

        convertStream.str(std::string());
    }

    return plainString;
}
```

Comment: so awesome!  is `ClassA::ParseXMLOutput` the name of your function, or does that come from a lib, or what?  tyvm for this!

Comment: @Gracchus It's the name of my function!

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler and standard library support the new [C++11 regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) you might be able to use [`std::regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace).

There are also other regular expression libraries you could use.

If you don't want to use regular expressions, then you could manually copy the string, while checking for "tags". When you see a `'<'` just continue looping without copying until you see a `'>'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already use tinyXML, iterate over all nodes depth-first and append the text of the node to the string you're building. There are some answers of SO on how to do that, i.e. [TinyXML Iterating over a Subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2582655/847349)